# Why is my Java app exceeding Heroku memory limit?

Tags: java, memory, heroku

I have a Java web app running on heroku which keeps generating "Memory quota exceeded" messages. The app itself is quite big and has a lot of libraries, but it is getting only very few requests (it is only used by a handful of users so if none of the users are online the system may not get a single request for hours) and thus performance is not a primary problem.

Even though the is very little happening in my app the memory consumption is consistently high:

[image: high memory consumption graph screenshot]

Before deploying the app on heroku I deployed the app using docker containers and never worried much about memory setting leaving everything at the defaults. The whole container usually consumed about 300 MB.

The first thing I tried was to reduce memory consumtion by using `-Xmx256m -Xss512k` however this did not seem to have any effect.

The heroku manual suggests to log some data about garbage collection, so used the following flags to run my application: `-Xmx256m -Xss512k -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`. This gives me e.g. the following output:

```
2017-01-11T22:43:39.605180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=588M(106.7%)
2017-01-11T22:43:39.605545+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431536+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-01-11T22:43:40.348+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-11T22:43:40.348+0000: [ParNew
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431566+00:00 app[web.1]: Desired survivor size 4456448 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431579+00:00 app[web.1]: - age   1:    7676592 bytes,    7676592 total
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431593+00:00 app[web.1]: - age   2:     844048 bytes,    8520640 total
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431605+00:00 app[web.1]: - age   3:     153408 bytes,    8674048 total
2017-01-11T22:43:40.431772+00:00 app[web.1]: : 72382K->8704K(78656K), 0.0829189 secs] 139087K->78368K(253440K), 0.0830615 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs] 
2017-01-11T22:43:41.298146+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-01-11T22:43:41.195+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-11T22:43:41.195+0000: [ParNew
2017-01-11T22:43:41.304519+00:00 app[web.1]: Desired survivor size 4456448 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
2017-01-11T22:43:41.304537+00:00 app[web.1]: - age   1:    7271480 bytes,    7271480 total
2017-01-11T22:43:41.304705+00:00 app[web.1]: : 78656K->8704K(78656K), 0.1091697 secs] 148320K->81445K(253440K), 0.1092897 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs] 
2017-01-11T22:43:42.589543+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-01-11T22:43:42.526+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-01-11T22:43:42.526+0000: [ParNew
2017-01-11T22:43:42.589562+00:00 app[web.1]: Desired survivor size 4456448 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 6)
2017-01-11T22:43:42.589564+00:00 app[web.1]: - age   1:    6901112 bytes,    6901112 total
2017-01-11T22:43:42.589695+00:00 app[web.1]: : 78656K->8704K(78656K), 0.0632178 secs] 151397K->83784K(253440K), 0.0633208 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
2017-01-11T22:43:57.653300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=587M(106.6%)
2017-01-11T22:43:57.653498+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

Unfortunately I am no expert on reading those logs, but on a first naive look it looks like the app is actually not consuming an amount of memory that would be a problem (or am I horribly misreading the logs?).

My `Procfile` reads:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT --context-xml context.xml app.war
```

### Update

As codefinger suggested I [added the Heroku Java agent to my app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/monitoring-jvm-metrics-with-the-heroku-java-agent). For some reason after adding the java-agent the problem did not occur anymore. But now I have bean able to capture the problem. In the following except the memory limit was exceeded only for a short moment:

```
2017-01-24T10:30:00.143342+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=92M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=221M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=233M
2017-01-24T10:30:00.143399+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=77M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=78M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-24T10:30:00.143474+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=41 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=24 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-24T10:30:00.147542+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4449M measure.mem.linux.rss=446M

2017-01-24T10:31:00.143196+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=103M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=251M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=251M
2017-01-24T10:31:00.143346+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=101M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=103M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-24T10:31:00.143468+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=42 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=25 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-24T10:31:00.153106+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4739M measure.mem.linux.rss=503M

2017-01-24T10:31:24.163943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=517M(101.2%)
2017-01-24T10:31:24.164150+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

2017-01-24T10:32:00.143066+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=108M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=248M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=248M
2017-01-24T10:32:00.143103+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=108M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=110M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-24T10:32:00.143173+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=40 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=23 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-24T10:32:00.150558+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4738M measure.mem.linux.rss=314M

2017-01-24T10:33:00.142989+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=108M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=248M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=248M
2017-01-24T10:33:00.143056+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=108M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=110M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-24T10:33:00.143150+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=40 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=23 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-24T10:33:00.146642+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4738M measure.mem.linux.rss=313M
```

In the following case the limit was exceeded for a much longer time:

```
2017-01-25T08:14:06.202429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:14:06.202429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:14:26.924265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:14:26.924265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:14:48.082543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:14:48.082615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:15:00.142901+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=164M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=229M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=233M
2017-01-25T08:15:00.142972+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=121M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=124M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-25T08:15:00.143019+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=40 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=23 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-25T08:15:00.149631+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4740M measure.mem.linux.rss=410M
2017-01-25T08:15:09.339319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:15:09.339319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:15:30.398980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:15:30.399066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:15:51.140193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=574M(111.5%)
2017-01-25T08:15:51.140280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-01-25T08:16:00.143016+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=165M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=229M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=233M
2017-01-25T08:16:00.143084+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=121M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=124M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M
2017-01-25T08:16:00.143135+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.threads.jvm.total=40 measure.threads.jvm.daemon=23 measure.threads.jvm.nondaemon=2 measure.threads.jvm.internal=15
2017-01-25T08:16:00.148157+00:00 app[web.1]: measure.mem.linux.vsz=4740M measure.mem.linux.rss=410M
```

For the later log here is the bigger picture:

[image: memory limit exceeded]

(memory consumption dropped because I restarted the server)

At the time the memory limit is first exceeded a cron job (spring scheduled) imports CSV files. The CSV files are processed in batches of 10,000 lines, so there are never more than 10K rows referenced in memory. Nevertheless a lot of memory is of course consumed overall, as many batches are processed. Also I tried to trigger the imports manually to check whether I can reproduce the memory consumption peak, but I can't: This does not always happen.

Comment: Have you tried [Monitoring JVM Metrics with the Heroku Java Agent](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/monitoring-jvm-metrics-with-the-heroku-java-agent)? What libraries are you using? Some libraries (like Ehache use lots of off-heap memory).

Comment: The logs say the app is using 587M of memory, which is more than the 512M limit

Comment: @codefinger: I added more logs to my question. Also I am using a lot of libraries, especially the Ecosystem around the spring framework. But I am not aware of using anything that uses off-heap memory, but maybe that is wrong. How can I find out?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but may help:

I looks like you have a surge (or possibly a leak) in off-heap memory consumption. The source is almost certainly the CSV processing. Here's a good article that describes a similar problem.
http://www.evanjones.ca/java-native-leak-bug.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have exceeded about:

Process running mem=574M(111.5%)

maybe it is impossible do decrease under 500 in your app, i had similar problems with app and now my app works correct under 512MB.
you can try some of these options (my docker example):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dserver.port=$PORT","-Xmx268M","-Xss512K","- 
XX:CICompilerCount=2","-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8","- 
XX:+UseContainerSupport","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
Xlog:gc","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

of course Xmx value you have to match to your case (maybe more maybe less)